# Linux Environment Variables in EventMachine run loop

Tags: ruby, rubygems, eventmachine

I have a simple ruby file that uses Eventmachine for to act as a daemon. It look like this:

```
...
EM.run {
   Signal.trap('INT') { @log.debug("trapped INT signal"); stop(true) }
   Signal.trap('TERM') { @log.debug("trapped TERM signal"); stop(true) }

   EM.add_periodic_timer 60 do
        puts ENV['TEST_ENV']
   end
}
...
```

After running it, I get nothing printed for TEST_ENV when `echo $TEST_ENV` clearly shows the variable is defined before the process is started.

How can I make sure my daemon can see the environment variables?

Comment: Didn't you forget to `export TEST_ENV` ?

Comment: No. I probably should have mention that the environment variable is set and available outside EM loop. Although I mention that echo $TEST_ENV clearly shows the variable is defined.

Answer (score 0):

All I can really say, unless there is more to the example that you aren't showing is, works for me:

```
petunia ~/t $ cat t.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
  EM.add_periodic_timer(5) do
    puts ENV['TEST_ENV']
  end
}


petunia ~/t  $ TEST_ENV=test ruby ./t.rb 
test
```